# Energy loss from an ideal string due to sudden increase in tension

Tags: classical-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws

Say there are two masses in gravity free space, connected by an ideal string of length L. The initial distance between the masses is d < L. The string is slack. One of the masses is now given an initial velocity V, perpendicular to the line joining the masses. Work out the velocities of the masses after the string becomes taught.

I can solve the problem under the assumption that the components of final velocities of the masses are same along the string. My questions are:

1) Is this assumption correct?

2) Why is the final kinetic energy less than initial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my answer to [Force Transfer Between two bodies linked by a rope](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/273950).

An ideal string is massless and inextensible. It is also elastic, but with an infinitely large spring constant. No energy is lost when it becomes taut and jerks back on the two masses.

As Farcher says, this can be treated as a collision type of problem.  Both momentum **and kinetic energy** are conserved. The easiest way of applying conservation of energy is via the *coefficient of restitution*, which is 1 for elastic collisions. So measuring velocities along the string at the instant of the "collision" :

relative velocity of separation = relative velocity of approach.

So the answers to your questions are :

1) Not in general. If the 2 masses are equal, the velocity (along the string) of the moving mass A is transferred to the stationary mass B. This is equivalent to a 1D collision of a ball A moving with speed v towards a stationary ball B of equal mass : the result is that A is stationary and B moves away from A with speed v.

2) There is no loss of kinetic energy.

Comment: That answers it. I do have two more questions. 1)does the condition for 'e' come from kinetic energy equations? And 2) in a non ideal string, is hysteresis the source of energy loss? Is it the only source?

Comment: 1) $e=1$ is the condition for conservation of kinetic energy. $e^2$ is the proportion of mechanical energy retained after collision. 2) Hysteresis is a vague term. It is used with a number of meanings. Generally it means the same as energy loss when something has gone through a cycle and returned to the initial state with less energy than it started. In a real string there could be plastic (permanent) deformation. The material does not return to its initial state, so this could not be described as 'hysteresis'.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is a variation of colliding spheres.
The mass $m$ which is initially not moving suffers an impulse along the line of the string at an angle $\theta$ to the initial direction of the velocity of $V$ of other mass $M$.
So immediately after "collision" mass $m$ must travel along the line of the string.

[image]

From the geometry of the system just before the sting becomes taut gives you angle $\theta$ in terms of lengths $L$ and $d$.

As no external forces are acting momentum is conserved.
However you do not have enough information to solve this problem without making a further assumption which in this case is probably that "the collision is elastic" with kinetic energy being conserved.

Comment: This is a problem my teacher solved in the class. I thought the same thing about missing information, but he said that is included in the fact that the string is ideal. Hence the assumption that the final velocity components along the string are the same. In this case, however, it turns out that the KE is not conserved. This leads to my second question, where did the energy go? I thought that, since the string is ideal, it couldn't have gained or lost any energy. But that contradicts the result.