# Why is energy conservation not valid here?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, energy-conservation, string

I was solving this question and I faced a problem :

[image]

See the problem is I know the conventional way of impulse momentum and energy conservation to solve this question but ,

I do not know why applying energy conservation from starting to end that is when the ball is released from rest to the time the the ball is at its lowest position that is , at a distance 50 cm below its final position ,

I do not understand why energy conservation fails ?

Work done by tension = 0 , No external force acting on the system even if I consider a hinge force on the thread , then also work done by hinge force is zero .

[image]

This is the impulse method

Would be highly helpful if you could help me solve this question with elastic collision condition , I know the Youngs modulus , area of cross section of the string as well .

In summary I would say that this is a inelastic collision because if it was not then momentum conservation would not fail , in an inelastic collision energy cannot be conserved hence energy cannot be conserved , like wise this is also not a partially elastic or partially inelastic collsion because then the question will be out of scope .

For those looking for impulse calculation , at the time of impulse , the velocity along the length of string will become zero and hence only the perpendicular component will survive , the string is extensible but not that much that we can say a velocity along parallel direction will also survive .

Comment: When the string turns taut for the first time, it is equivalent to a collision, and mechanical energy can be converted into heat and sound energy in a collision.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/279756/

Comment: Hey there they say that no energy will be lost

Comment: this is an ideal string

Comment: In that problem, they did not specify enough to solve the problem without assuming conservation of energy. It is also with two masses that are free to move. Here, you have a fixed point. By fixed, really, it is a connection to the entire Earth. You would have serious difficulty seeing the Earth itself move. It appears as a loss of energy.

Comment: Why would you assume energy is not conserved?

Comment: If energy is not conserved then my impulse momentum method fails

Comment: Voting to reopen. Clear a conceptual question about the correct approach to this type of problem, not a "do my homework for me" question.

Comment: I think you are failing to conserve energy, because you are completely ignoring gravitational potential energy.

Comment: There is collision, elastic or otherwise, there is an external force (gravity) and the impulse method is just a complicating distraction, when all you have to do is convert gravitational potential energy to kinetic energy. Job done.  The fact that ball free falls initially is just a red herring. Conservation of energy still applies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ball falls straight down travelling a distance of $40\,\rm cm$ (3,4,5 triangle) at which point the downward velocity of the ball is $v$ which can be found by the application of the conservation of mechanical energy.

[image]

Just before the string becomes taut the velocity of the ball $v$ has two components; one parallel to the string $v_{\parallel}$ and the other perpendicular to the string $v_{\perp}$.
On becoming taut the string imparts an impulse along to the string $I$ on the mass which reduces the parallel component of velocity to zero but the impulse does not affect the perpendicular component of velocity.
This is equivalent to an inelastic collision and so mechanical energy is not conserved.

The ball then falls a further distance to reach the bottom of its trajectory with mechanical energy being conserved.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152153/discussion-on-answer-by-farcher-why-is-energy-conservation-not-valid-here); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.