# Rotational velocity of tethered shape after falling

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, energy-conservation

[image: Question]

My solution to the above question involves equating the potential energy to the to the kinetic energy at the point at which the wire tightens as:
$$
\frac{1}{2}mv^2 = mgh
$$
However, I am having trouble finding the initial rotational velocity of the object, I initially thought that it was, if l is length:
$$
\omega = \frac{2}{l} v
$$
However, seeing a this is a full (past) exam question, I think the solution if not as straightforward.  My second thought was that perhaps the radius of rotation is the distance from the connection point to the centroid of the shape and v the velocity component perpendicular to this.
But I am not sure that all of the velocity after falling is converted into rotational velocity at that instant, or if the point of connection accelerates to the right at the point as the string becomes taut.

Answer (score 2):

You solve this problem with impulses. There is a impulse $J$ acting on the connection point *A* causing the velocity of *A* to go from $v$ to zero.

The change in velocity at *A* is $$\Delta v_A = -v$$ where $v=-\sqrt{2 g d}$ is the speed after dropping a distance $d$. It is negative because it is downwards.

The change in velocity at *A* in terms of change in velocity at the center of mass *C* is

$$  \Delta v_A = \Delta v - \frac{w}{2} \Delta \omega $$ where $w=300$ is the width of the block.

The equations of motion at the center of mass *C* are

$$ \begin{align} J & = m \Delta v \\ -\frac{w}{2}\,J &= I_C \Delta \omega \end{align} $$ where $m$ is the mass and $I_C = \frac{m}{12}(w^2+h^2)$ the mass moment of inertia of the block.

All four equations above are combined to solve for the impulse $$ J = - \frac{I_C m v}{I_C + m \left( \frac{w}{2} \right)^2 } $$

remember that $v$ is negative, so $J$ is positive.

The center of mass speed after the event is

$$ \begin{align} vx_C & =0 \\ vy_C &= v + \Delta v = v + \frac{J}{m} = \frac{ \left( \frac{w}{2} \right)^2 m v }{I_C + m \left( \frac{w}{2} \right)^2 }\end{align} $$ which is negative (downwards).

The angular velocity afterwards is found from the 4th equation

$$\omega =0 + \Delta \omega =- \frac{ \frac{w}{2} J}{I_C} = \frac{\left( \frac{w}{2} \right) m v}{I_C +m \left( \frac{w}{2} \right)^2} $$

which is used to find the velocity of *B*

$$ \begin{align} 
vx_B & = 0 + \frac{h}{2} \Delta \omega = \frac{ \left( \frac{w}{2} \right)^2 m v}{I_C + m \left( \frac{w}{2} \right)^2}  \\
vy_B & = v + \Delta v + \frac{w}{2} \Delta \omega = \frac{2 \left( \frac{w}{2} \right)^2 m v}{I_C + m \left( \frac{w}{2} \right)^2} 
\end{align} $$

Comment: Thank you. So the solution must consider the mass and mass moment of inertia? If so could the problem be solved by equating kinetic energy to the rotational energy $$\frac{1}{2}I \omega^2$$ (Taking the moment of inertia through A)

Comment: If it is rotating, then mass moment of inertia must be considered. The kinetic energy in fact is $K=\frac{1}{2}m v^2 + \frac{1}{2} I_C \omega^2$

Comment: Why does the velocity of corner A become zero immediately after the impulse? You seem to be assuming that the "collision" is inelastic. I think the correct (physical) approach is to treat the string as elastic, so kinetic energy is conserved.

Comment: The _OP_ question mentions the wire is taut and I took it to mean continually and not instantaneously. You are right we can use $$\Delta v_A = -(1+\epsilon) v$$

Answer (score 0):

When the string becomes taut, I think the velocity of corner A does not become zero. Real strings are to some extent elastic and aren't usually permanently deformed by becoming taut. In such an experiment the plate is observed to "bounce" back upwards, while at the same time spin with high angular speed.

So I think the correct treatment for an **ideal** string is to assume that **kinetic energy is conserved** when it pulls back on the falling plate. It remains inextensible by having a very high spring constant. See my answer to [Force Transfer Between two bodies linked by a rope](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/273950).

The result is that the impulse from the string reverses the velocity of the CM of the plate from $v=\sqrt{2gh}$ downwards to $v$ upwards, while an impulsive torque of $2mva$ changes the angular velocity of the plate. Here $2a=300mm$ is the width of the plate.

For real strings there is in fact some loss of energy due to hysteresis, so the CM of the plate does not "rebound" to its original height. This could be accounted for using a *coefficient of restitution* (e) as for collisions, so that the plate rebounds with speed $ev$.