# How to work out conservation of momentum when there's impulsive tension in play?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, momentum, velocity

[image]

I need help with this problem. The point mass is hitting the block with velocity u at angle θ and then sticks to it. What will be the velocity of the combined mass immediately after collision?

What I tried so far:

I can see that the tension will be impulsive, so can't conserve momentum along the initial direction of motion.

So, I conserved momentum in the horizontal direction, but that gives me only one equation.

What should I do in the vertical direction?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is a string. Would you kindly tell me how to draw these sketches? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at this as two collisions in series : (i) the inelastic collision of the point mass with the block, immediately followed by (ii) the elastic collision of the combined object with the object attached to the other end of the string. In this case, the other end of the string is attached to an immovable object. In all cases both momentum and kinetic energy are conserved  in the collision mediated by the string.

(i) Resolve the velocity of the point mass perpendicular and parallel to the string - ie $v_x=v\cos\theta, v_y=v\sin\theta$.

If the string were not there, the components of velocity of the combined object immediately after the collision would be given by conservation of momentum : $\frac12v_x$ to the right and  $\frac12v_y$ downwards.

(ii) Immediately after the collision of the point mass and block there is a collision between the combined object and the immovable support at the other end of the string. The string is elastic, conserving kinetic energy. The effect is that the velocity of the combined object parallel to the string is reversed.

So the final velocity of the combined object has components $\frac12v_x$ to the right and $\frac12v_y$ **upwards**.

Thereafter, the string becomes slack for a while, until the object has moved far enough for it to become taut again, whereupon there will be another elastic collision between the combined object and the support, mediated by the elastic string.

---

Note : see my answers to the similar questions
[Force Transfer Between two bodies linked by a rope](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/273950)
[Find the speed of two balls joined by a string and the impulse in the string when the string goes taut](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/309785)
[Rotational velocity of tethered shape after falling](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/304082).